# Is there an axios cache adapter for Cache API?

Tags: axios, cacheapi

Is there an extension for axios that uses Cache API to cache responses on requests with [Cache API](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/cache-api).

(Or maybe an example how to implement it yourself?)